# Remove function from a jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I remove a function from a jquery object? For example, I have

```
$('#element').func = function() {
     // function body goes here
}
```

And later on I want to remove `func` from `$('#element')`. I've tried `delete` but it doesn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about this?

```
$('#element').fn.func = null;
```

or

```
$('#element').prototype.func = null;
```

or

```
delete $('#element').fn.func;
```

or

```
delete $('#element').prototype.func;
```

For understanding what the prototype is, have a look here: [How does JavaScript .prototype work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work)

Answer (score 1):

you can do  by assigning null.

```
$('#element').fn.func = null;
```